# Failing to test prop types for React.js project with jest framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-proptypes

In my React.js app - I've set up the prop types check [like this](https://github.com/xameeramir/React-TDD-Sample/blob/fa557ba4689a9dbd80d7ccb8cb65c118e423d470/src/Congrats/Congrats.component.js#L19)

```
Congrats.propTypes = {
    success: PropTypes.bool
};
```

I'm testing these prop types with [the following test](https://github.com/xameeramir/React-TDD-Sample/blob/fa557ba4689a9dbd80d7ccb8cb65c118e423d470/src/Congrats/Congrats.test.js#L33):

```
test('does not throw warning with expected props', () => {
    const expectedProps = { success: false };
    checkProps(Congrats, expectedProps);
})
```

`checkProps` looks [like this](https://github.com/xameeramir/React-TDD-Sample/blob/fa557ba4689a9dbd80d7ccb8cb65c118e423d470/test/testUtil.js#L10):

```
export const checkProps = (component, conformingProps) => {
    const propError = checkPropTypes(component, conformingProps, 'prop', component.name);
    console.log('propError', propError)
    expect(propError).toBeUndefined();
}
```

For some reasons, the above test is failing with the following error:

> Congrats: prop type `propTypes` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from React.PropTypes

So, I changed the proptypes definition to [the following](https://github.com/xameeramir/React-TDD-Sample/blob/aae266da1baf72cd7e287795e03c0ac1a07770ef/src/Congrats/Congrats.component.js#L19):

```
Congrats.propTypes = {
    success: React.PropTypes.bool
};
```

which throws the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined

Can someone please guide me on how to make this test pass?

Comment: [The README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-prop-types) suggests you should be passing `component.propTypes` as the first argument to `checkPropTypes`, not the whole component.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, it works! thanks :)